# Google Cloud SQL & PHP tutorial isn't editing database?

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm learning how to use Google Cloud SQL and am trying to connect to the database using PHP. I'm following the [Google instructions here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/).

I created 3 files (`guestbook.php`, `sign.php`, and `app.yaml`) and copied the code as presented in the article. In order to connect to the database, I used the `PDO_MySQL` variant.

In `guestbook.php` and `sign.php`, in the `if` statement: I replaced `<your-project-id>` and `<your-instance-name>` as appropriate. I left the `''` for the password empty.

In `guestbook.php` and `sign.php`, in the `else` statement: I replaced `127.0.0.1` and `<password>` as appropriate. I left the `3306` as is.

In `app.yaml`: I replaced `<your-application-name>` as appropriate.

I then saved the 3 files in a local directory and then deployed it using the `GoogleAppEngineLauncher`.

When I loaded the first page, everything looked fine. I typed in something and hit `Submit`. I then got redirected to the page `/guestbook`, but then was told:

```
Error: Not Found

The requested URL /guestbook was not found on this server.
```

I am very new to web apps and PHP in general. I have no idea what this error message is asking me to do. I've already uploaded the files to the Google server using the App Launcher. I'm confident I've followed the instructions closely.

Some things I've tried doing:

1. In `guestbook.php` and `sign.php`, I filled in `''` with an appropriate password.
2. In `guestbook.php` and `sign.php`, I deleted the default `3306`.
3. In `guestbook.php` and `sign.php`, I deleted the `if` statement and only used the content of the `else` statement.
4. In `app.yaml`: I added `-url: /guestbook`.
5. In `guestbook.php` and `sign.php`, I switched from `PDO_MySQL` to `mysqli`.

None of the attempts above did anything to solve the problem. Attempts 1 also resulted in the message `Unable to connect.`.

**EDIT:**

In `sign.php`, I changed `header('Location: '."/guestbook");` to `header('Location: '."/");`. That seems to have gotten rid of the `URL not found` error, but it seems like nothing in my database is being altered. The PHP is doing nothing to change the database.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this problem and connect, read, and write to my database?

Comment: Do you see any error log in the cloud console? Have you authorized your GAE app to access the CloudSQL instance?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem... did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Their guestbook PHP code is broken, plain and simple. They try to do a redirect (using the Location header) after they already output the  and  tags, which is illegal.

The result of this is, if you're not logged in, the code is *supposed* to redirect you to a login page, but it doesn't. And then when you try to post to the guest book, the "$user" is null, so the page fails.

Oh yeah, and the sign.php page redirects to /guestbook, which you correctly identified doesn't exist. And it redirects at the top of the sign.php code, which will obviously make the code afterwards do nothing. Here's some fixed code.

Guestbook.php:

```
<?php
use google\appengine\api\users\User;
use google\appengine\api\users\UserService;

$user = UserService::getCurrentUser();

if ($user === null) {
  header('Location: ' . UserService::createLoginURL($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
}
?>

<html>
 <body>
  <h2>Guestbook Entries</h2>
  <?php
  // Create a connection.
  echo 'Hello, ' . htmlspecialchars($user->getNickname()) . '<br>';

  $db = null;
  if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) &&
  strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'],'Google App Engine') !== false) {
    // Connect from App Engine.
    try{
       $db = new pdo(mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/<your-project-id>:<your-instance-name>;dbname=guestbook', 'root', '');
    }catch(PDOException $ex){
        die(json_encode(
            array('outcome' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to connect.')
            )
        );
    }
  } else {
    // Connect from a development environment.
    try{
       $db = new pdo('mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3306;dbname=guestbook', 'root', '<password>');
    }catch(PDOException $ex){
        die(json_encode(
            array('outcome' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to connect')
            )
        );
    }
  }
  try {
    // Show existing guestbook entries.
    foreach($db->query('SELECT * from entries') as $row) {
            echo "<div><strong>" . $row['guestName'] . "</strong> wrote <br> " . $row['content'] . "</div>";
     }
  } catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo "An error occurred in reading or writing to guestbook.";
  }
  $db = null;
  ?>

  <h2>Sign the Guestbook</h2>
  <form action="/sign" method="post">
    <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook!!"></div>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And sign.php

```
<?php
use google\appengine\api\users\User;
use google\appengine\api\users\UserService;

$user = UserService::getCurrentUser();
if (!$user) {
  die("Not logged in");
}

$db = null;
if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) &&
strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'],'Google App Engine') !== false) {
  // Connect from App Engine.
  try{
     $db = new pdo('mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/<your-project-id>:<your-instance-name>;dbname=guestbook', 'root', '');
  }catch(PDOException $ex){
      die(json_encode(
          array('outcome' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to connect.')
          )
      );
  }
} else {
  // Connect from a development environment.
  try{
     $db = new pdo('mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3306;dbname=guestbook', 'root', '<password>');
  }catch(PDOException $ex){
      die(json_encode(
          array('outcome' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to connect')
          )
      );
  }
}
try {
  if (array_key_exists('content', $_POST)) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO entries (guestName, content) VALUES (:name, :content)');
    $stmt->execute(array(':name' => htmlspecialchars($user->getNickname()), ':content' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['content'])));
    $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
    // Log $affected_rows.
  }
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
  // Log error.
}
$db = null;
header('Location: '."/");
?>
```

Comment: Hey. I just read your comment above and was writing an answer to it when you posted this answer. You're absolutely right that their PHP code was completely broken. I managed to fix it as well, but forgot to update here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you figured it out too. I reported the documentation issue to them.